# could not convert string to float: '1,6800'

Tags: python

I am currently working on a trading algorithm. It's supposed to calculate the average of the stock price(which I get from yahoo finance).For that I must convert the string it gives me to a float but when I try, it gives me this weird error which I can't fix.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



pricelist = []
pricelen = len(pricelist)
tr = True

while tr:
    url = 'https://de.finance.yahoo.com/quote/WDI.DE?p=WDI.DE&.tsrc=fin-tre-srch'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    price = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'})[0].find('span').text
    f = float(price)
    print(f)
```

Here is the error:

```
could not convert string to float: '1,6800'
```

Thanks in advance

Igor

Comment: You need to replace ',' with '.' because in python float values represented with '.'

Comment: something like this, ``float("1,6800".replace(",",""))``

Comment: I'd also consider [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) for anything that involves prices.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did as suggested and it worked out perfectly.

Comment: @igor if an answer helped you, consider marking that answer as accepted to help future visitors to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you convert a string to int it expects only numeric characters

in the same way for floats it only expects `.` or numeric characters

now the easiest way to handle other characters is to replace them

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



pricelist = []
pricelen = len(pricelist)
tr = True

while tr:
    url = 'https://de.finance.yahoo.com/quote/WDI.DE?p=WDI.DE&.tsrc=fin-tre-srch'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    price = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'})[0].find('span').text
    f = float(price.replace(',','.')) #ONLY CHANGE
    print(f)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, consider adding some explanation to make it more useful to others in the long run

Comment: @MLarionov I was editing the answer mate, hopefully it helps now

Answer (score 1):

Python can't handle the comma in the string value. You'll have to remove it before you parse it as a float. The simplest way to do this is with `replace()`:

```
float(price.replace(",", ""))
```

If the comma is meant to be a decimal place, use the following:

```
float(price.replace(",", "."))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use filter to remove everything except the digits and then convert it.

```
price = '$1,6800'
numbers = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, price))
f = float(numbers)
print("{0:.2f}".format(f))  #print upto 2 decimal places
```

Hope it helps.